# Spotlight: Don't Index a Volume

Tags: spotlight

Is it possible to ask Spotlight to not index a volume ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, open the **Spotlight prefpane** and under the **Confidentiality** tab (not sure, but on my  French system it is called "Confidentialité"), you can add folders and volumes not to be indexed.

Comment: Privacy on English systems.

Answer (score 8):

There are a variety of options to do this:

1. Add the drive to the "Privacy" tab in the Spotlight Preference Pane
2. Turn off Spotlight indexing for the site from the command line: `sudo mdutil -i off /Volumes/NAME_OF_DRIVE`
3. `touch /Volumes/NAME_OF_DRIVE/.metadata_never_index` on an external drive.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a removable volume, create a file in its root directory called .metadata_never_index, as in [this hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060814124808745).