# how to stop spotlight indexing an attached camera

Tags: spotlight, privacy

When I attach my video camera (for the purpose of importing some clips into FCP-X) I noticed that spotlight is indexing the camera (which does show up as an external disk when I connect it, via the USB cable)  I'm pretty sure that there is some contention between spotlight trying to index these files and FCPX trying to import them.  Is there a way to stop Spotlight from indexing the attached disk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spotlight: Don't Index a Volume](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3319/spotlight-dont-index-a-volume) The other answer has several command line options to disable spotlight as desired.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if one can use Terminal to write a file on the camera?  Or would the camera delete extra files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy

Add your camera once and it should be remembered.